# How to make React Native Animated.View clickable?

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, react-native

I'm using this react native tinder demo -> https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-animated-demo-tinder

Is it possible to make the cards 'clickable' so it would navigate to another view on click? I've tried wrapping the "Touchable" components around the animated view but doing so disables the animations.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess you can use TouchableX inside the `Animated.View`

```
import { Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
<Animated.View>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
      stuff
    <View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

Ensure you are using the correct imports (not react-native-gesture-handler) otherwise it might not work on Android.

Comment: I did it but it disabled the animations. Did you got its solution @Denny?

Comment: The view renders -- a `backgroundColor` of the `<TouchableOpacity>` can be rendered, but the `onPress` event does not register.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you vice-versa the order of `Animated.View` and `TouchableOpacity` then on some iPhones it won't work - the view will not be always touchable (it's unpredictable as I figure out)

Comment: additional <View> here is redundant since TouchableOpacity itself is a View and understands all the View's props

Answer (score 55):

Another method (which worked better for me) is to create AnimatedTouchable component using createAnimatedComponent method of Animated:

```
const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);

<AnimatedTouchable onPress={this.onPress}>
  stuff here
</AnimatedTouchable>
```

Comment: actually this should be the selected answer because wrapping in a `Animated.View` may mess your styling and require unnecessary `View`

Comment: Only `onPress` is working, but not animation. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Try using <Animated.View> and see if animations work this way. If not then you probably not animating correctly

Comment: I did this but onPress is not even working, the entire TouchableOpacity isn't even responding to any press event.

Comment: @Oleg i was able to solve it, it was due to native-base

Answer (score 11):

my variant. This custom `AnimatedPressable` can also be used inside `Animated.View`.

```
import {Text, Animated, Pressable} from 'react-native'
    
const AnimatedPressable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Pressable);
    
export default () => {
  return (
     <AnimatedPressable onPress={()=>alert('test onPress')}>
        <View>
           <Text>{'....'}</Text>
        </View>
     </AnimatedPressable>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was not working on Android, when I was using

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Use `TouchableOpacity` provided by React Native.

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);

<Animated.View>
<AnimatedTouchable onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
      <BackButton style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} />
    </AnimatedTouchable>

</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's too late but in my case i have set the height of Animated.View less than the content inside it

so make sure that the Animated.View height must be greater or equal to the content on which TouchableOpacity is placed

Answer (score 1):

What about checking ref value? In example below I use swipes and simulate `<TouchableOpacity />` onPress action by checking `translation.dx._value`

```
export const CoolComponent = () => {
  const theme = StyleSheet.create({
    blockPosition: {
      transform: [{translateX: translation.x}],
    },
  });

  const translation = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0})).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
        [
          null,
          {
            dx: translation.x,
          },
        ],
        {
          useNativeDriver: false,
        },
      ),
      onPanResponderRelease: checkTranslationCoords,
      onPanResponderTerminate: checkTranslationCoords,
    }),
  ).current; 

  const checkTranslationCoords = () => {
    if (Math.abs(translation.x._value) === 0) {
      // TouchableOpacity action here
    }
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      style={[theme.blockPosition]}
    >
      <Text>Some text</Text>
      </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me when i tried to make a dismissable bottomsheet by pressing on backdrop

was this :

```
const renderBackdrop = () => {
const animatedBackdropOpacity = Animated.interpolate(fall, {
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0.5, 0],
});

return (
  <Animated.View
    pointerEvents={pointerEvents}
    accessibilityViewIsModal
    accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={_closeBs}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.backdropContainer,
          {
            opacity: animatedBackdropOpacity,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </Animated.View>
);
```

};

Credit goes to React Native Paper Modal Component
https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/components/Modal.tsx#L184

Answer (score -5):

you need to write a method to animate inside the .

```
renderButton: function() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('./myButton.png')}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
},
```

in top of the render () you need to write the animated style with in this method

```
_onPressButton(){
........
........
}
```